# JVM segmentation faults due to "Invalid memory access of location"

Tags: scala, jvm, segmentation-fault, sbt, scalatest

I have a small project written in Scala 2.9.2 with unit tests written using ScalaTest. I use SBT for compiling and running my tests.

Running `sbt test` on my project makes the JVM segfault regularly, but just compiling and running my project from SBT works fine. Here is the exact error message:

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x8 rip=0x10959f3c9
[1]    11925 segmentation fault  sbt
```

I cannot locate a core dump anywhere, but would be happy to provide it if it can be obtained.

Running `java -version` results in this:

```
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

But I've also got Java 7 installed (though I was never able to actually run a Java program with it, afaik).

Another issue that may be related: some of my test cases contain titles including parentheses like `(` and `)`. SBT or ScalaTest (not sure) will consequently insert square parens in the middle of the output. For example, a test case with the name `(..)..(..)` might suddenly look like `(..[)..](..)`.

Any help resolving these issues is much appreciated :-)

**EDIT:** I installed the Java 7 JDK, so now `java -version` shows the right thing:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

This also means that I now get a more detailed segfault error and a core dump:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010a71a3e3, pid=16830, tid=19459
#
# JRE version: 7.0_07-b10
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.3-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3cd3e3]
```

And [the dump](https://gist.github.com/4240715).

**EDIT**: Changing the scalaVersion to 2.9.1 gave the following error once, then the same error as above:

```
Could not load hsdis-amd64.dylib; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
[thread 25091 also had an error]
```

Comment: Can you get a minimal set of code and unit tests that still reproduces the problem, and post that?

Comment: I'll try. I have busy weekend, so I'll get back to you next week.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM segfaulting is usually indicative of bad system memory, especially when not being pushed to its limits.

Run memtestx86 overnight.

Comment: memtestx86 doesn't seem to run on OS X. I did run MemTest a couple of times and it didn't identify any errors. I'm pretty sure this is not a memory issue. I didn't run into any problems except when running tests from the SBT repl. It happens approximately on every 10th run.

Comment: @Dan: Intermittent crashes are guaranteed memory or computer issues. You've done nothing wrong with scala, sbt, or Java.

Comment: @Dan How about trying to reproduce on a different machine?

Comment: @ziggystar, I actually did that. A friend of mine is running ArchLinux. He installed Scala and SBT (also with Java 7) and ran the tests. His JVM also crashed, so it cannot be a hardware issue.

Comment: @Jatin, here's [a zip](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/131288/nussinov.zip) containing all tests and code (plus build.sbt). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Dan It worked well for me. ore info here (https://www.stypi.com/purijatin/untitled). More details on the link.

Comment: @Jatin, I have to run it around 10 times to make the crash occur (it could be different for you though).

Comment: @Dan I have written script and tested for 100 times, no issue with mine. interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues on a toy project I'm building to learn scala [1](https://github.com/noelhollingsworth/project). A solution I found that seemed to stop the seg faults was changing the scala version in build.sbt to version 2.9.1. I'm not sure why this helped.

Comment: That's very interesting! Just tried it out. After a few runs I now got a different error, but now I'm back to the old one. See the original post for the new error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error. A lot of poling and prodding found that it happened around a loop that allocated many arrays with Array.ofDim. Replacing that with Array.fill seems to have fixed the issue for me.